Is there a way to balance client bandwidth between webrtc video and http fetch requests?
I have a web-rtc video calling app that works fine with high quality over 4g, however, if I am also uploading data via the fetch api at the same time the quality of the web-rtc video goes through the floor and is basically unusable.
Is there a way to balance network priority from the browser between a web-rtc connection and fetch requests?
Things I have tried...

Limiting the web-rtc bandwidth on the sender to 750kbps but there is no difference, what I really need to do is limit the bandwidth of the fetch or specify a minimum bandwidth for the web-rtc video
set fetch priority to "low" and sender priority to "high" but these settings seems to only work relative to the same kind of transport (not across http & web-rtc)
I have already reduced the size and frequency of the http requests as much as possible

I realise its all about the balance between quality and speed but I just need to be able to tweak that balance so that it is acceptable for both the video call and the fetch.

This is working as designed and called TCP-friendlyness. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2_MVsuA0CY describes the choices made quite well.
It is not quite what you would expect from a UX perspective though...
